# ChatJS jquery.chatjs.adapter.demo.js for multiple users

Tags: chatjs

I took a look at ChatJS today, but I am not sure how to go about completing the jquery.chatjs.adapter.demo.js adapter code as the coder suggested. If you take a look at the example file you will find a bot replying the same message in the chat room. What I want is to be able to chat with multiple users online. I can load in the users from any source for now and probably worry about the connection later. If someone has a working adapter code for ChatJS please let me know, I will be using it with ASPX. I am not sure if I need the signalR adapter for this to work.

Comment: I'm also looking forward to this, I think if we want to use this code with SignalR we will solve our problem. But what we need to write code for this SignalR Adapter  to get the user list from DB and and how to intergrate to our project. I test some but all fail. Hope any master help us!